# Problem adding .ics file to Iphone X Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ical

I had a problem adding .ics files to my Iphone X calendar. I created an .ics file on my other Android phone and I am able to add this .ics-file-event to my Google calendar and many others. But when I send it to my Iphone X via Whatsapp, I can't add it to my default IOS calendar. It always says:

```
This invite is outdated
```

And there is no button to add it to my calendar. I am not sure, if it is a coding issue in my .ics file or something else. Surprisingly it's perfectly working on the Iphone 6 calendar.

That's my .ics file code.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-Nick//0.6.3//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dabfe592-49f3-4428-93cd-1026b90c0004
DTSTAMP:20190728T143648Z
SUMMARY:Test
DESCRIPTION:Test
LOCATION:Test
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190914
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks for help